# Maven Build - Class Files Size is reduced

Tags: java, maven, build

I am trying to mavenize an existing project. 
I was able to build the EAR file(since i have to deploy in Websphere), When I try to deploy, using admin console - Able to install successfully , But application is not working, After investigating, I found the `class files` size is very less compare to the reference EAR file(old existing EAR file)

Steps I followed to build the EAR file

1. M2E plugin installed
2. Configure to Maven
3. Add **ALL** the jar files from `lib` folder like below(I read in SO, this is not the recommended way, but to complete the project, I have to do this)

```
<dependency>
<groupId>JarFile</groupId>
<artifactId>JarFile</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/CRDBXMLExternal.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

4. Added the relevant plugins `(war, EAR)`
5. Clean Build and Install.
6. `ear` file created. `ear` contains a `war` file, which has all the project related files including `class`,`jsp` etc.

I compared the folder structure with the existing EAR file and its contents , all look good. But only the size of class files(Not ALL but more than 80%) are varying. I use JD to `decompile` and see the code, Most of the code are not present, including `imports`.

If anyone has encountered similar issue , could you please tell me what am doing wrong here.

More Info

there are two project folders(both are maven) one will create WAR and another one EAR in EAR pom.xml
there is a dependency

```js
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.comp.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>war</type>
 </dependency>
```

Then there is a plugin

```js
<build>
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.10</version>
   <configuration>
    <version>5</version>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <generatedDescriptorLocation>C:\COMP\Dev\may\repos\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</generatedDescriptorLocation>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>      
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Adding WAR file building(Removed most of the dependencies kept only one sample) POM.xml

```js
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.comp.abc</groupId>
 <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>ABC</name>
 <description>ABC</description>

 <dependencies>
  <!-- Local Repository -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</groupId>
   <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>



 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>nexus-releases</id>
   <name>nexus</name>
   <url>http://abc-nexus.ldn.xyz.com:9080/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <excludes>
     <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
   </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugins>   
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
     <!-- <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}\WebContent</warSourceDirectory> -->
     <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First follow the convention over configuration paradigm and remove the configuration to change the sourceDirectory there is no advantage in doing so...furthermore a Maven build which contain absolute path in the pom configuration is simply wrong...there is no need for it...you should use packaging:ear to produce an ear file and furthermore you should use a repository manager to handle artifacts which are not distributed via maven central. You should put them there..afterwards you can use them as usual dependencies.Also the war packaging should be changed and follow the conventions....

Comment: A usual multi module project which creates WAR/EAR files looks like this: See this example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have a few questions here
1. Adding the jar files in `lib` folder and pointing through pom.xml , will not work or its just a violation of best practice ?                                                                        2.This is an existing project , which has two modules - should i change both the modules to Maven ? or is it okay to change only the `web` and make it as `ear` package.                                                                               3.exmple has many modules.could you pls simple ex (2 modules), so that a beginner like me can follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, 
`web/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` is not getting updated.
but I could see the latest `classes` under `web/target/classes` path.
Now am checking why `web/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` is not getting updated.

Just now got the Resolution from the below Link :-
ISSUE SOLVED by with the help of 
https://coderanch.com/t/474423/ide/ecplise-doesn-create-classes-folder

Steps

Right click on your project -> build path -> Configure build path -> click on source tab -> click on browse (Default output folder).

After browsing click on WebContent -> Select WEB-INF -> Create new folder (called classes). it will open new window.

Give folder name as classes. Click on Advanced and give path of current classes folder means WEB-INF/classes.

After doing this, eclispe will rebuild your project and classes will be genenrated at WEB-INF/classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

The above does not tell Maven to package the EAR file with the `lib` directory dependency. It actually tells it to create local dependency on an existing JAR that is provided only at compile time. Thus, when you export the EAR, it does not include any of the JARs because it assumes that they are provided at runtime.

You should use the maven-ear-plugin which package an EAR file instead. You can find the full documentation [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html).

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: actually, when i unzip the ear -> war file all the jars are available

Comment: How do you export the EAR, do you specify `<packaging>ear</packaging>` and depend on the `mvn package` target to create the EAR file?

Comment: Could you please specify the module that does not compile properly under the `</configuration>` section of the plugin. An example would be `<modules>
            <webModule>
              <groupId></groupId>
              <artifactId>web</artifactId>
            </webModule>
            <ejbModule>
              <groupId></groupId>
              <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
            </ejbModule>`

Comment: Added the entire POM.xml which builds the WAR. removed the dependencies for convenience other wise this is the complete POM.xml. BTW am doing this for the first time.